# Возможно ли двоеточие после во-первых / во-вторых / в-третьих?

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие

> Но во-первых: похоже, он отлично знал местность и переулок за его
>   спиной был пуст, а неподалеку притаился перекрёсток. Во-вторых:
>   продавец был силён и видно было, что в голове его сложился вполне
>   конкретный план. В-третьих: в киоске героя было несколько комплектов
>   деревянных мечей…

Если не двоеточие, то мы утопнем в запятых... Понятно (мне), что знаки диктует первое предложение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При обособлении вводных слов довольно часто используется **не запятая, а тире**, например: **И главное** ― ну куда человек без высшего образования, пусть даже и неоконченного?  Думаю, что двоеточие  может применяться на тех же основаниях.

К примеру, в этой статье ставится двоеточие после во-первых, во-вторых: http://www.raapa.ru/userfiles/files/mag2.pdf

Answer (score 1):

96 вхождений в Нацкорпусе, например:

> Роджер оказался превосходным парнем. Во-первых: он был солдатом. [Д. А. Гранин. Месяц вверх ногами (1966)]
>
> Мечта каждого доброго россиянина ― и заключённого, и вольнонаемного, ― чтобы его поставили что-нибудь, кого-нибудь проверять. Во-первых: я над кем-то командир. Во-вторых: мне оказано доверие. [В. Т. Шаламов. Колымские рассказы (1954-1961)]